# Nested React Routers Child print coming undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to limit route acess. Its getting blocked but when I login those urls component do not print or children I am trying to print are not printing any idea why? **this.props.children value is undefined** URLs I am trying to block are getting blocked.

**RequireAuth.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';


let isLoggedIn

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class RequireAuth extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("token");
        this.checkAuth();
        console.log(this.props, "Hello", this.props.children)
    }

    checkAuth() {

        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            history.push(`/#/SignIn`);
        }
        window.location.reload();

    }


    render() {

        return(
            let RouteChildren = 

React.cloneElement(this.props.children)
        return(
            {RouteChildren}
    )
        )
    }
}


export default withRouter(RequireAuth);
```

**Routes I am trying to put condition on**

```
<Router onUpdate={ () => window.scrollTo(0, 0) }>
                <div className="app">
                    <Switch>


                        <Route exact path="/LogOut" component={LogOut} />

                        <Route component={RequireAuth} >
                            <Route exact path="/HomeProfile" component={HomeProfile} />
                            <Route exact path="/HomeProfile/HomePictures" component={HomePictures} />
                            <Route exact path="/HomeProfile/HomeRecord" component={HomeRecord} />
                            <Route exact path="/HomeProfile/HomeSystems" component={HomeSystems} />
                            <Route exact path="/Rewards" component={Rewards} />

                            <Route exact path="/Settings/ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />

                            <Route exact path="/Settings/Notification" component={Notification} />
                        </Route>


                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<Router>` and wrapping your `<Route>` inside it ?

Comment: @Aaqib I guess router can be used just once. so i have updated code above see if still required.

Comment: why are you using clone?i believe  React.cloneElement example only work if your child is a single React element

Comment: @Aaqib so what do you suggest?